# TAB completion does not work in Jupyter Notebook but fine in iPython terminal

Tags: jupyter-notebook, readline, jupyter, tab-completion, ubuntu-15.10

TAB completion works fine in iPython terminal, but not in Firefox browser.

So far I had tried but failed,

1). run a command `$ sudo easy_install readline`,

then the .egg file was wrote in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/readline-6.2.4.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg,`

but TAB completion still doesn't work in Jupyter Notebook.

2). also tried to find locate the `ipython_notebook_config.py or  ipython_config.py`, but failed.

I use Python 3.5 and iPython 4.0.0.  and both are installed in Ubuntu 15.10  `/usr/share/anaconda3/bin/ipython`.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: FYI, in my case, run the command $ conda update readline, and now the TAB completion works fine in Jupyter Notebook.  But still I don't know why.

Answer (score 126):

It's a known issue and jedi is the problem. Try executing:

> `pip3 install jedi==0.17.2`

https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/2435

Comment: this is a good answer that worked for me (ubuntu 20.04, pyhton3.8). 
I had jedi version 0.18. After installing the 0.17.2 version all tab completion problems were gone.

Comment: Had to re-run all code (">>") before it took effect.

Comment: I was running jupyter lab on windows, and this fixed my tab completion problem

Comment: Running JupyterLab on MacOS 10.14.6, Python 3.8.1. Worked for me!

Comment: You can upgrade iPython instead. Refer to [python - Completion in IPython (jupyter) does now work (unexpected keyword argument 'column') - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65843310/completion-in-ipython-jupyter-does-now-work-unexpected-keyword-argument-colu/65862512#65862512)

Comment: This is not a good answer anymore. Pinning to an outdated version one year after release of compatible IPython version will only make your environment more susceptible to old bugs and security concerns patched in later versions. Instead you should upgrade IPython.

Comment: Still a thing in 2023 - conda install jedi==0.17.2 after conda list showed 0.19.1 was installed.

Answer (score 40):

My problem was in that I try to call autocomplete and import in the same cell.
Because of imported thing does not initialized yet, autocomplete does not work.

All I need is call to the object in a new cell
[image]

UPD: or just run program once in the same cell to initialize imported

Answer (score 26):

I've just installed the latest JEDI then helped me to solve that issue, here's the command when using Anaconda:

```
conda install -c anaconda jedi
```

Or you might need to try this, copy this line on the top of your jupyter notebook:

```
%config Completer.use_jedi = False
```

Answer (score 24):

```
%config Completer.use_jedi = False
```

This command helps but we need to add it to all the notebooks again and again.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! It is already part of another answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65647689/2359227 If you nothing to elaborate please consider upvoting the other answer and delete yours. Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: I dont have reputation to comment, how to earn reputation ?

Comment: [What is reputation? How do I earn (and lose) it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)

Comment: ipython profile create, you can use this command to generate a config file in /Users/zhivarsourati (my root directory )/.ipython/profile_default

Answer (score 13):

you can add

> %config IPCompleter.greedy=True

in the first box of your Jupyter Notebook.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar issue and unfortunately cannot comment on a post, so am adding an easy solution that worked for me here.  I use conda and **conda list** showed I was running jedi-0.18.0.  I used the command **conda install jedi==0.17.2**.  This quickly fixed the problem for my conda environment.

Additional note: I usually use jupyter-lab, and was not seeing the error messages generated.  By switching to jupyter notebook, I saw the following error:

> [IPKernelApp] ERROR | Exception in message handler: Traceback (most
> recent call last):   File
> "D:\apps\miniconda\envs\pydata-book\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py",
> line 265, in dispatch_shell
> yield gen.maybe_future(handler(stream, idents, msg))   File "D:\apps\miniconda\envs\pydata-book\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py",
> line 762, in run
> value = future.result()   File "D:\apps\miniconda\envs\pydata-book\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py",
> line 234, in wrapper
> yielded = ctx_run(next, result)   File "D:\apps\miniconda\envs\pydata-book\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py",
> line 580, in complete_request
> matches = yield gen.maybe_future(self.do_complete(code, cursor_pos))   File
> "D:\apps\miniconda\envs\pydata-book\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\ipkernel.py",
> line 356, in do_complete
> return self._experimental_do_complete(code, cursor_pos)   File "D:\apps\miniconda\envs\pydata-book\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\ipkernel.py",
> line 381, in _experimental_do_complete
> completions = list(_rectify_completions(code, raw_completions))   File
> "D:\apps\miniconda\envs\pydata-book\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\completer.py",
> line 484, in rectify_completions
> completions = list(completions)   File "D:\apps\miniconda\envs\pydata-book\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\completer.py",
> line 1815, in completions
> for c in self._completions(text, offset, _timeout=self.**jedi**_compute_type_timeout/1000):   File "D:\apps\miniconda\envs\pydata-book\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\completer.py",
> line 1858, in _completions
> matched_text, matches, matches_origin, jedi_matches = self._complete(   File
> "D:\apps\miniconda\envs\pydata-book\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\completer.py",
> line 2026, in _complete
> completions = self._jedi_matches(   File "D:\apps\miniconda\envs\pydata-book\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\completer.py",
> line 1369, in *jedi_matches
> interpreter = **jedi**.Interpreter(   File "D:\apps\miniconda\envs\pydata-book\lib\site-packages\jedi\api_*init**.py",
> line 725, in **init**
> super().**init**(code, environment=environment, TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'column'

I highlighted a couple of the jedi messages, but this all reinforced it was a problem related to the version of jedi installed.

Comment: I too ran into this issue. One note when using nb_conda_kernels: I had to downgrade jedi to 0.17.2 in the same environment as my ipykernel and not the one in which I have jupyterlab installed.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, after running `pip install pyreadline`, I needed to re-execute all the lines in Jupyter before the completion worked. I kept wondering why it worked for IPython but not Jupyter.

Answer (score 4):

In my case I installed miniconda on Debian Linux and most likely had a problem with the previous Python that was included with Debian. The following lines solved my problem:

```
conda update conda
conda update --all
```

The solution was taken from [here](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/2240) based on the error that I had in IPython in terminal after writing `np.<tab>`:

```
No such file or directory: '/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python'
```

Comment: These steps got tab autocomplete working for me on Windows 10/Anaconda.

Answer (score 3):

The answer from Sagnik above (Dec 20, 2020) works for me on Windows 10.

pip3 install jedi==0.17.2

[Sorry I'm posting this as an answer instead of comment. I have no permission to comment yet. ]

Answer (score 2):

The workaround I found is to assign the intermediate result to a temporary variable.then in seperate cell, using tab on temporary variable for auto-completion.

temp = pd.Description

temp.**TAB**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, resolved using

```
conda install -c anaconda jedi
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue under my conda virtual env in windows pc and downgrading the jedi to 0.17.2 version resolved the issue for me.

conda install jedi==0.17.2

Answer (score 0):

faced the same problem, for me the following worked

```
conda install -c anaconda jedi
```

Answer (score 0):

The best fix I've found for this issue was to create a new Environment. If you are using Anaconda simply create a new environment to fix the issue. Sure you have to reinstall some libraries but its all worth it.

Answer (score 0):

F.wo.huang's comment on the OP worked for me in my anaconda environment:

```
condo update readline
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating a new env variable helped me to solve this problem.

Use `environments.txt` content in `.conda` as path.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I was using miniconda,
I switched to anaconda and that seems to have solved the issue.
PS. I had tried everything I could find on the net but nothing resolved it except for switching to anaconda.

Answer (score 0):

As the question was asked five years ago, the answer was likely different back then... but I want to add my two cents if anyone googles today: The answer by users Sagnik and more above worked for me.

One thing to add is that if running anaconda, you can do what I did: simply

- start the anaconda-navigator software,
- locate the jedi package in my environment,
- click the little checkbox on the right of jedi
- under "Mark for specific version installation", choose 0.17.2

After restarting the kernel everything worked :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the command below as discussed [here](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/12740)

`pip install -U ipython==7.20`

Answer (score 0):

I updated Jupyter Notebook to version 7. Everything works now.