# Parameters of python's functions doesn't appear when I hit 'tab'

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

It might sound stupid, but the jupyter notebook I'm using is, probably, not configured as it should.

Everytime I hit 'tab' when the cursor is within a function, the parameters doesn't appear in the top of the list. Any tip here?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WGCp.png)

Answer (score 0):

Found this on stack over flow [TAB completion does not work in Jupyter Notebook but fine in iPython terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33665039/tab-completion-does-not-work-in-jupyter-notebook-but-fine-in-ipython-terminal)

are you using firefox aswell?

the solution seems to be to run:

```
pip3 install jedi==0.17.2
```